# Объявление интерфейса в интерфейсе

Tags: java, интерфейс

> Тело интерфейса может объявлять **члены интерфейса**, т.е. поля, методы, классы и **интерфейсы**.

Смысл работы интерфейса мне вроде бы понятен, но хотелось бы дополнить свое понимание ответом на следующий вопрос. Для чего может понадобиться объявлять интерфейс в интерфейсе?

Comment: В качестве предположения: для того же, для чего и используются static nested-классы – для группировки сущностей по контексту.

Comment: Абстрактный класс унаследовать от интерфейса, в нем добавить абстрактные методы. Класс, унаследовать от абстрактного....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В практике, если честно, я такого не встречал, а если бы и встретил — постарался бы уйти от этого, потому что это может усложнять код. Да и по законам чистого кода, одна сущность (класс, метод, интерфейс) — одна задача и не более. Делать вложенные интерфейсы и классы, обычно, не самая лучшая затея (хотя и иногда бывает нужно, как, например, в шаблоне `Builder`).

---

Но, если все-таки предположить, что такое возможно и придумать ситуацию, у меня  вышло так:

```
   public interface ProjectMaker {
        interface MakeHelper {
            void makeThisPart(Project project);
            void makeAllParts(Project project);
        }

        void makeProject(MakeHelper maker);
    }

    public class SomeClass {
        ProjectMaker mProjectMaker = ...;

        public void makeSomeClass {
            mProjectMaker.makeProject(new ProjectMaker.MakeHelper() {
                @Override
                public void makeThisPart(Project project) {
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void makeAllParts(Project project) {
                    ...
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

P.S. Не стоит "на ходу" создавать реализации интерфейсов, как в методе `makeSomeClass()`. Лучше сначала создать объект, который реализует интерфейс и передать уже его.

Comment: так же сюда, на мой взгляд можно отнести <ActionName>Listeners, которые так часто используются при разработке под android. Там тоже достаточно часто можно встретить внутри интерфейса интерфейсы. Например интерфейс View имеет интерфейс ClickListener привязанный к конкретному вью

Comment: @abbath0767, `View` — это же класс. Или есть интерфейс с аналогичным названием?

Comment: Если мы про View из android api, то да класс. Но я об абстрактной сущности. То есть мы можем объявить свой интерфейс View  со своим интерфейсом для Callback'ом. Например множество похожих по поведению элементов, можно объединить общим интерфейсом с интерфейсом. (вообще можно сделать множеством способов, но это как пример возможной реализации)